# Utility to monitor vsftpd.log

Tags: linux, log-files, ftp

Is there a Linux utility that can monitor vsftpd.log an extract bandwidth usage information for every user ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe AWStats does VSFTPD bandwidth usage information.

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

I'm not 100% sure about each user (i personally use ProFTPD+MySQL) but hopefully that helps.

Comment: Can you give me more details about ProFTPD+MySQL? Can that show traffic for every user ?

Comment: Yep.   And because its in SQL, I can freely query it how i want to.

http://www.howtoforge.com/proftpd_mysql_virtual_hosting

Shows how to setup ProFTPD and MySQL for "Virtual Hosting", and http://www.iezzi.ch/archives/110 gives a little more information on how to setup ProFTP to log to a MySQL table.